# Xubuntu crashes before login screen

Tags: xubuntu, login, lightdm

- Xubuntu 13.10

Booted up this morning and Xubuntu does not get to the login screen. I am seeing the white half circle spinning and then it drops to a black screen.

I can however start tty1-6 but that doesn't help me much because this has never happened before, hence I don't know what to do at the moment.

As far as I know, I did not perform any changes to xfwm4, LightDM by text (in config files). Installed a Numix theme via PPA and played around with some settings for the XScreenSaver but all that happened via GUI and some simple terminal commands (adding a PPA). That is about it I'd say.

Some notes:

- An update via

  `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`

did not help.

- Going forth and back between tty1 and tty7 did not help.
- Graphics: Intel HD something. So no NVIDIA or AMD card.

Does anyone have any pointer what I could do to solve the problem? It would be greatly appreciated. :)

Any info I could provide via `| pastebinit`?

**edit**

What do you know. There is something broken with X or LightDM. So I logged in via tty1 and then just typed `startx` and hit Enter. I'm in Xubuntu now and as you can see, it's working, however all fonts looks really odd. Somehow the anti-aliasing settings in the appearance options for XFCE were reset. Hm, what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable numlock on startup, I added the line

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. That was the reason lightdm crashed. So now that I have taken it out, it all works flawlessly again.